# Laço de repetição for

Tags: c

O meu código só está imprimindo o ultimo caso.Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Meu Código...

```
include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int teste,total,i;

    float percentpop,percentgeral,percentarq,percentcad,renda,pop,geral,arq,cad;

    scanf("%d",&teste);

    for(i=1;i<teste;i++){

                scanf("%d %f %f %f %f",&total,&percentpop,&percentgeral,&percentarq,&percentcad);
                pop=total*(percentpop/100);
                geral=(total*(percentgeral/100))*5;
                arq=(total*(percentarq/100))*10;
                cad=(total*(percentcad/100))*20;
                renda=pop+geral+arq+cad;
                     }
    for(i=1;i<teste;i++){
            printf("A RENDA DO JOGO N. %d E = %.2f\n",i,renda);
     }

      return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara suas variáveis são sobrescritas durante o laço, a impressão deve ser feita ao final de cada iteração, ou você deve guarda-lás e mostrar depois...

Comment: O enunciado apresentado em forma de imagem não é muito util, particularmente para dispositivos moveis. Melhor seria colocar o mesmo na forma de texto facilitando a leitura a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, sua variável é sobrescrita toda vez que entra no laço. Para poder imprimir o resultado após as iterações, pode armazenar isso em um vetor, de forma bem simples. O tamanho, vai depender do que você precisa, então eu coloquei uma variável chamada MAX que controla o tamanho do mesmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//DEFINE TAMANHO DO VETOR
#define MAX 10
int main(){
    int teste,total,i;
    float percentpop,percentgeral,percentarq,percentcad,pop,geral,arq,cad;
    float renda[MAX];
    scanf("%d",&teste);

    for(i=0;i<teste;i++){ 

    scanf("%d %f %f %f %f",&total,&percentpop,&percentgeral,&percentarq,&percentcad);

    pop=total*(percentpop/100);
    geral=(total*(percentgeral/100))*5;
    arq=(total*(percentarq/100))*10;
    cad=(total*(percentcad/100))*20;
    //salvando cada resultado em uma posicao do vetor
    renda[i] = pop+geral+arq+cad;
}

    for(i=0;i<teste;i++) printf("A RENDA DO JOGO N. %d E = %.2f\n",i+1,renda[i]);
    return 0;
}
```